# Running python script on when user unlocks windows machine

Tags: windows-xp, python, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script , which I want to run , when user unlocks the machine 
ie; When users presses Cntl-Alt-Delete and enters username and password and logs in.

How can I do this ? . Is there any registry value , I can add that

pythonw.exe C:\myscript.py  to that so that , it runs myscript.py everytime , user unlocks the machine ?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows XP, use PyWin32 to:

- `win32gui.CreateWindow()` an invisible window
- call `win32ts.WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`
- listen for `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` window messages having `wparam == WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK`

  - *lparam* will be the session ID
- An example implementation is included below.

If you want the script to work for *multiple* users, convert it to a *service* (`win32serviceutil` is handy for this); see `wtsmonitor-svc.py` at the above address.

---

##### Example program

1. Edit `events.py` to suit your needs.
2. For a single user, run:

   ```
   wtsmonitor.pyw
   ```

   For a system-wide service, run:

   ```
   wtsmonitor-svc.py --startup auto install
   wtsmonitor-svc.py start
   sc query WTSMonitor
   ```

Attachment 1/3: `wtsmonitor.pyw`

```python
#!python
# (c) 2011 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
# Released under the MIT license <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT>
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import subprocess

try:
    import win32api as api
    import win32con as con
    import win32gui as gui
    import win32ts as ts
except ImportError:
    print("wtsmonitor: PyWin32 modules not found", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    import events
except ImportError:
    print("wtsmonitor: events.py not found", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# window messages
WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE        = 0x2B1

# WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE events (wparam)
WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT     = 0x1
WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT      = 0x2
WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT      = 0x3
WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT       = 0x4
WTS_SESSION_LOGON       = 0x5
WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF      = 0x6
WTS_SESSION_LOCK        = 0x7
WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK      = 0x8
WTS_SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL  = 0x9

methods = {
    WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT:        "ConsoleConnect",
    WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT:     "ConsoleDisconnect",
    WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT:     "RemoteConnect",
    WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT:      "RemoteDisconnect",
    WTS_SESSION_LOGON:      "SessionLogon",
    WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF:     "SessionLogoff",
    WTS_SESSION_LOCK:       "SessionLock",
    WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:     "SessionUnlock",
    WTS_SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL: "SessionRemoteControl",
}

class WTSMonitor():
    className = "WTSMonitor"
    wndName = "WTS Event Monitor"

    def __init__(self, all_sessions=False):
        wc = gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.hInstance = hInst = api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = self.className
        wc.lpfnWndProc = self.WndProc
        self.classAtom = gui.RegisterClass(wc)

        style = 0
        self.hWnd = gui.CreateWindow(self.classAtom, self.wndName,
            style, 0, 0, con.CW_USEDEFAULT, con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 0, hInst, None)
        gui.UpdateWindow(self.hWnd)

        if all_sessions:
            scope = ts.NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS
        else:
            scope = ts.NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION
        ts.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(self.hWnd, scope)

    def start(self):
        gui.PumpMessages()

    def stop(self):
        gui.PostQuitMessage(0)

    def WndProc(self, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):
        if message == WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
            self.OnSession(wParam, lParam)
        elif message == con.WM_CLOSE:
            gui.DestroyWindow(hWnd)
        elif message == con.WM_DESTROY:
            gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
        elif message == con.WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
            return True

    def OnSession(self, event, sessionID):
        name = methods.get(event, "unknown")
        print("event %s on session %d" % (
            methods.get(event, "unknown(0x%x)" % event), sessionID))

        try:
            method = getattr(events, name)
        except AttributeError:
            method = getattr(events, "default", lambda e, s: None)

        method(event, sessionID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = WTSMonitor(all_sessions=True)
    m.start()
```

Attachment 2/3: `wtsmonitor-service.py`

```python
#!python
# (c) 2011 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>
# Released under the MIT license <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT>
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import win32service as svc
    import win32serviceutil as svcutil
except ImportError:
    print("wtsmonitor-svc: PyWin32 modules not found", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

import wtsmonitor

class WTSMonitorService(svcutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "WTSMonitor"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Terminal Services event monitor"
    _svc_description_ = "Runs custom actions on Terminal Services session events."
    _svc_deps_ = ["TermService"]

    m = None

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(svc.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.m.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(svc.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.m = wtsmonitor.WTSMonitor(all_sessions=True)
        self.m.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    svcutil.HandleCommandLine(WTSMonitorService)
```

Attachment 3/3: `events.py` (example)

```python
#!python
# See the 'methods' dict in wtsmonitor.pyw for a list of possible events.

def default(event, session):
    pass

def unknown(event, session):
    pass

def SessionLock(event, session):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Task Scheduler (Vista and higher) or the Scheduled Tasks control panel (WinXP) to create a scheduled task that triggers "At logon" or "On workstation unlock." I believe such a trigger will cause the task to execute in the scenario you describe.

Comment: Nope. I just tried and it didn't ran.

Comment: There's also an "On workstation unlock" trigger. Give that a try.

Comment: in windows xp ?

Comment: No, I believe "On workstation unlock" may be limited to Vista and higher. There may be a way to achieve similar results on xp but it's probably not as straightforward. You might want to add "XP" to your original question (or the tags) if "XP" is the required platform. BTW, I just verified that "On workstation unlock" works as expected on Vista by having it send mail to myself.

Answer (score 0):

you should check [Schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run, and end scheduled tasks on a local or remote computer. Running Schtasks.exe without arguments displays the status and next run time for each registered task.

Comment: it can run only on logon and not on while user unlocks the machine.

Comment: check here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx in the "/sc" parameter there is a ONLOGON value that following their description should do what you need