# How do I automatically exit a program when I lock the screen on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to auto-exit a program on Windows 7 whenever I lock the screen?

Comment: Is there a particular program you have in mind? Is there a nice way to exit the program without using `taskkill`?

Comment: Disregard my questions, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per grawity's suggestion, **do not use the batchfile I put** at the end of this answer.  This is because `rundll32.exe` *does not* match the calling convention of the `LockWorkStation` Win32 API function (see [this MSDN blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/01/15) for details).  That being said, there is a better alternative, which doesn't involve too much work.

You can use the [AutoIt scripting language](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and the [`DllCall`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DllCall.htm) function to call a Win32 API function without corrupting the call stack.  You can also use the [`ProcessClose`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ProcessClose.htm) instead of `TASKKILL`.  For your reference, [here is the `LockWorkStation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation) reference from the MSDN.

Place the following two lines in a file, and save it as `exitandlock.au3` (or something similar).  You can then run it with AutoIt (or even compile it into a .exe if you want).

```
ProcessClose("yourapp.exe")
DllCall("user32.dll", "BOOL", "LockWorkStation")
```

That should provide you with what you want, without corrupting the call stack.  You can then bind that file to a hotkey and use that to lock your workstation.  Alternatively, you can compile it into a .exe file, and set it to run as a scheduled task after your computer is inactive.

Finally, you may also want to use the [`WinClose`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinClose.htm) function as an alternative to `ProcessClose`.

---

As I said, please **do not use this method**.  I keep it here only for completeness, as this is one of the most widely used ways on the internet.  You can use a simple batchfile to do this using the `TASKKILL` command:

```
@ECHO OFF
TASKKILL /IM yourapp.exe
Rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Then, just run the batchfile when you want to lock your workstation.  Alternatively, you could also assign a hotkey to execute the batchfile, and then just hit that key combo when you want to lock it.  For more details on the `TASKKILL` command, see [this article from Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20171016213040/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: @KCotreau: `taskkill` just sends WM_CLOSE; it doesn't terminate the process unless you use `/f`.

Comment: @grawity Thank you. That is very good to know.

Comment: @Breakthrough: [Do not use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) `rundll32` to call `LockWorkStation()`.

Comment: @grawity good to know, I was not aware of that.  I am coming up with another solution, will post it soon.

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1: Write a script that will terminate the program

Create a file named `terminate.vbs` with these contents:

```
set objwmiservice = getobject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
strprocessname = wscript.arguments.item(0)
strquery = "select * from win32_process where name='" & strprocessname & "'"
set colitems = objwmiservice.execquery(strquery,,48)
for each objitem in colitems
    objitem.terminate
next
```

Test this script by opening a command prompt and executing `cscript.exe "C:\path\to\terminate.vbs" notepad.exe`. Replace `notepad.exe` with the process name that you want to terminate.

### Step 2: Schedule the script to run when you lock the screen

Open **Task Scheduler** (you can search in the Start menu for it), right-click **Task Scheduler Library** and select **Create Task...**. On the **General** tab, give your task a name and description. You can change **Configure for:** to *Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2* if you want, but that is not necessary.

[image: Create Task - General tab]

On the **Triggers** tab, create a new trigger and set **Begin the task:** to *On workstation lock*. The rest of the default settings are fine.

[image: Create Task - New Trigger]

On the **Actions** tab, create a new action that will *Start a program*. **Program/script:** should be *cscript.exe*. Enter the path to `terminate.vbs` and the process name you want to terminate in the **Add arguments (optional):** box. My arguments are `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\terminate.vbs" notepad.exe`

[image: Create Task - New Action]

You can check the **Conditions** and **Settings** tabs for more options, but none of those are necessary here. Save the task, and you are done. When you lock the screen, the process should terminate.

Note that if you lock the screen, then unlock quickly, you might see a command prompt window or the process you want to terminate still in the process of terminating. This depends on how long it takes the process to terminate gracefully.

Comment: instead of handwritten vbscript you can say taskkill /IM notepad.exe 
Anyway, thanks for the tip about the trigger - I could not find it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a program using `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` to wait for *`WTS_SESSION_LOCK`* events and do the necessary stuff.

An example can be found at: https://superuser.com/a/264973/1686